# Import "jsonschema" could not be resolved from sourcePylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I am attempting to use the jsonschema package to validate uploaded JSON payloads from the user.

I have run `pip install jsonschema` inside my venv and received a message confirming it's installation.

Running `pip freeze` confirms this.
[image]

When I attempt to import the package VS Code underlines the package with a yellow squiggly and says "Import "jsonschema" could not be resolved from sourcePylance"

[image]

I am able to access the validate function via autocomplete menus, however when I attempt to run via the VS Code run menu it fails with the following message

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jsonschema'"

If I run it manually from my terminal it executes the code as expected.

My launch.json is provided

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "app.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is caused by you choosing incorrect Python interpreter.

You can use "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the interpreter where you installed this package.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you MingJie-MSFT. I have not found a good article on using VS Code with Python and venv, but this helps me get closer to understanding the ideal setup.

Comment: @RobS. I think [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_python-environments) will help alot.